# Can't remove LFCR from text with the usual methods, Excel bug?

Tags: excel, newline

I have a list of strings littered with carriage return and line feed which I am trying to clean. I have tried the following methods:

- find and replace of CTRL+J in excel
- find and replace of ALT+0010/ALT+0013 in excel
- find and replace of ALT+010/ALT+013 in excel
- CLEAN in excel
- copy list in excel, paste into notepad++, save as txt, reimport into excel ("Â" character was added on import) and finally replace "Â"
- I've also tried the Text to Columns option with CTRL+J, absolutely no result whatsoever
- EDIT: SUBSTITUTE CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) in excel didn't work either

None of the above worked, my list still contains line feeds and carriage returns. Is this a bug in excel?

Manually deleting these is out of the question due to the size of the list. I tried replacing these characters in notepad++ with pipe, and importing back into excel (choose delimited by pipe upon import and then copy/paste transpose), but again, the list is too long.

Anyone ideas? 
Many thankZ

Comment: To whomever down voted my question: if I can be any clearer (other than adding the original file, which I can't at this point due to data protection reasons), you can always let me know, and everyone will benefit... :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems one can find/replace a LF but not the combo LFCR.

The following formula will replace the LFCR with a space:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(13)," ")
```

You can then `Copy` ► `Paste as values` to remove the formula.

Comment: Thank you, I've actually tried this too. Didn't work. I'll amend my post.

Comment: @zoltansn If that does not work, then there is either something about your environment that you have not shared, or you don't really have the `LFCR` sequence in those cells.  I suggest you upload a file demonstrating the problem to some sharing site, and edit your post to include a link

Comment: If I get a spare half hour, I can dummy down a small section and post it somewhere with a link. With regards to not having LFCR at the end of the string: pasting the list into notepad++ shows LFCR, pasting it into Sublime shows an empty character. Our web dev lead had just looked at it (he put me onto sublime) but couldn't tell me what else that character could be. Re environment: the excel file I'm working on contains a list copied and pasted from a pdf - not sure if that's of any interest?

Comment: @zoltansn Well, I'll be very interested in analyzing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove these items and manual methods ae too burdensome, then consider the following macro:

```
Sub KleanUp()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = Chr(10)
    s2 = Chr(13)
    Cells.Replace what:=s1, replacement:=""
    Cells.Replace what:=s2, replacement:=""
End Sub
```

It will remove CR and LF in data in the active worksheet, but **not** change formulas like:

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & A2
```

or:

```
="alpha" & CHAR(4+6) & "beta"
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not yet tried VB yet, I'll give it a quick go!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found working was pasting into Sublime, making everything visible, highlighting the characters, then CTRL+D highlight the same characters throughout the text, deleting them, then pressing space which added the spaces back to where the characters were between words and then copy back to excel and trim the lot.

Strangest thing I've ever seen...